# Why does using properties() in a statement with a MERGE clause result in indefinite stalling in Neo4j 3.3.0?

Tags: neo4j

I am using Neo4j 3.3.0 on MacOS.

I have a statement, such as

```
MERGE (test:test_type {test_id:"123"}) 
  RETURN properties(test)
```

I would normally expect the attributes of the object that was created (or already existed) to be returned, but instead I get a cryptic error in the logger:

```
2018-01-03 21:06:14.255+0000 ERROR Client triggered an unexpected error [UnknownError]: null, reference 40c2f8ee-ec47-4129-a5cf-45812facf4a0.
```

This occurs when using the Neo4j browser and when using the Python SDK.

Has the behavior of properties() changed, or is this a bug?

Comment: I think that this is a bug - in 3.3.0 and 3.3.1 it is repeated, in version 3.4.0-alpha04 it does not repeat (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug to me, I can see the same behavior in 3.3.1 as well. I see you created an [issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/10719) for it on github, thanks!

This one might have been on our radar already, but if not, we'll get it patched up.

Comment: In version 3.4.0-alpha04 it does not repeat (Ubuntu)